# postgresql - update, set DEFAULT in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get a syntax error when trying to update a table to using the DEFAULT keyword value inside a case statement, as follows:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET status =
     CASE
        WHEN ( st.status = '' ) THEN ( DEFAULT )
        ELSE ( ROUND( CAST(st.status as numeric) ) )
     END

FROM sourceTable st
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
LINE 4: ...                  WHEN ( tc.status = '''' ) THEN ( DEFAULT )
```

Looking at the docs now for a while, and I cannot see how this violates any rules of statement construction.

Previous code does using NULL does work

```
UPDATE tbl
SET status =
     CASE
        WHEN ( st.status = '' ) THEN ( NULL )
        ELSE ( ROUND( CAST(st.status as numeric) ) )
     END

FROM sourceTable st
```

My goal is to update the column to a default value, or to NULL if there is an empty string in the source table column.

Using NULL worked fine but updated the column to NULL of course, and the change to DEFAULT I would think would work - can anyone help with a syntax correction or alternative?

This chunk of code is generated by something processing various columns in different scenarios, so not looking for any alternative approaches to the problem as such (though I am open to any response) - just looking for a fix if possible, or an explanation of why the syntax won't work.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the default value for the column? Just specify it in `THEN ( default )`

Comment: How does `status` get an empty value if it has a `DEFAULT` value?  Something seems strange elsewhere in the code.

Comment: The empty string is in the source table status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PostgreSQL documentation for UPDATE syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) seems to say that you can set a column either to an expression or to a bare word `DEFAULT`, but not to an expression containing the keyword `DEFAULT`.

```
SET column_name = { expression | DEFAULT }
```

This syntax reference means the right-hands-side of the `=` can be an expression, or it can be `DEFAULT`. The notation of `{ X | Y }` means "either X or Y, pick exactly one."

The choice of using the `DEFAULT` keyword does not appear in the [documentation for value expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html). `DEFAULT` can be used as a special-case assignment in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` but only as an alternative to a value expression, not as part of a more complex expression.

To get around this, you'll probably have to read the DEFAULT value for the column from `information_schema.columns.column_default` for the respective table and column, then use the value literally in your UPDATE statement.

Comment: Or just `update tbl set status = round(cast(status as numeric)) where status <> ''; update tbl set status = default where status = '';`

Comment: @Abelisto, Nooo! All SQL operations must be done in one statement! (I'm joking)

Comment: Thanks, Bill - I see what you mean and take your word for it - and marked your answer correct - but don't see how the definition in the referenced docs syntactically discludes the keyword DEFAULT from being part of the left-side expression, nor was I able to find more details on the DEFUALT keyword (at least in my search today).  I'll use an alternative, yours or something like abelisto's comment to get it working - feel free to point me to something that clarifies that you can, in any case thanks again.